# How to show certain view when app is triggered through notification?

Tags: ios

I want to make such function:

When the notification of my app is fired, like the following image:

[image]

I swipe the app icon in the bar to the right, and the app should run and show a certain view.

But I don't know how to do it.

In my application:`(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, I write:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        NSString *objectIDURL = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"objectIDURI"];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
        EventViewController *eventViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EventViewController"];
        [eventViewController setEvent:[Event getEventByObjectIDURL:objectIDURL]];
        [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:eventViewController animated:NO];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But after my swiping the icon to the right, my app does not run at all.

Can anyone help?

Plus, I'm using storyboard, I don't know is it relevant.

Comment: does the if condition pass validation ?

Comment: `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

Comment: @rakeshNS, I'm not clear what's your question mean.?

Comment: if (localNotif) is true or false ?

Comment: @rakeshNS, it is a pointer, if (localNotif) should be true, when the app is launched through notification, I think

Comment: @Desdenova, should it be "application:didReceiveLocalNotification"? And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never said if this was a local or remote notification, but the messaging works pretty much the same for both. You must keep in mind that the system notifies you differently if the app is running, or if its not running. That is, if you double click the home button and see the app's icon at the bottom, then its "running" (my terminology).

What you need to do is make sure you have all the relevant delegate methods implemented, and please, NSLog every one of them, so you can verify which are being messaged as you test. Copy and paste them from UIApplication.h, so that you don't have a typo (that is, a misspelling, as the system gives you no warnings on these!)

Implement all of the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // if launched due to a notification, you will get a non-nil launchOptions
  NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions=%@", launchOptions);
  ...
}

// if using remote notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  // Better get this for remote notifications
  NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: token=%@", deviceToken);
  ...

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"YIKES! didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError");
  ...
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
  // if already running, notification came in
  NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo=%@", userInfo);
  ...
}


// if using local notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  // if already running, notification came in
  NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification: notification=%@", notification);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using local notification, and I'm now wonder how can I debug using NSLog? For example, if I want to test didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I have to close the app in my iPhone first, then XCode will throw a signal SIGKILL and I can no longer see the NSLog.

Comment: The log messages get output to the device console log - you can see them in the Xcode Organizer window - go to devices, open up your device, then look at the log.